# select options wont show in react

Tags: reactjs, select, search, menu

I have a list of cities and I want them to be selectable. But it wont even show.
when I remove the first `<Col>` (just the col not the content of it) it works well so the problem is that col but I dont know why!
here is my code:

```
  function SearchBar() {
    const [open , setOpen] = useState(true)

      const cities= [
        {value:'tehran' , label:'tehran'},
        {value:'Esfehan' , label:'Esfehan'},
        {value:'Qom' , label:'Qom'},
        {value:'Mashhad' , label:'Mashhad'},
        {value:'Shiraz' , label:'Shiraz'},
         ]

return (
    <Container className="search-sec">
        
        <Form>
            <Row>
                <Col lg={7} md={5} sm={12} xs={12}>
                 <div className="job-field"> 
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" 
                  placeholder="job title, keywords or company name"/>
                </div>
                </Col>
                
                <Col lg={4} md={5} sm={12} xs={12}>
                   
                 <select onClick={() => setOpen(true)} className='city-field'>
                        { 
                            cities?.map((c) =>
                        <option key={c.value} value={c.value}>{c.label} 
                         </option>
                            )}
                </select>
                
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </Form>
       
    </Container>
)
```

}

Comment: open state is false by default so why would the options show up?

Comment: The `open` state is equal to `false` and your code `open && cities.map`  so the select options will show only when the `open` is equal to `true`.

Comment: I edited  the question, please take a look. thanks a lot

Comment: make it `lg={6}` and check

Answer (score 0):

As of now when you click on dropdown then `open` is `true` then you are able to see dropdown list.

You given condition `{open &&`  so when this `open` flag is true then only your options will displayed. you can remove that to see the dropdown.

```
<select onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>
  { 
    cities.map((c) =>
  <option value={c.value}>{c.label}</option>
      )}
</select>
```

Comment: thanks. I did what you said but it still does not work

Comment: its working for me. are you sure you are calling this component somewhere ? like this `<SearchBar />`

Comment: yes! 
besides  the code that I put here is a part of a from. but I don't think that would be a problem.
can share the compelete component with you somewhere else?

Comment: yeah that would be better but its working for me

Comment: @fatemehzamanipour have look same code working as expected.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tzhucs

Comment: I found out something and edited  the question, please take a look. thanks a lot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235757/discussion-between-fatemeh-zamanipour-and-amruth).

Answer (score 0):

why your `select` is dependent on the open state? I think you better do it as simple as  :

```
<select>
    {
     cities?.map((c) =>
          <option value={c.value}>{c.label}</option>
    )}
</select>
```

Comment: I edited  the question, please take a look. thanks a lot